# Unexpected value 'MyCustomModule' imported by the module 'AppModule'

Tags: angular, webpack, angular2-modules

I am trying to migrate one of my angular2 custom library to RC.6 + Webpack. My directory structure is:

```
- src - source TS files
- lib - transpiled JS files + definition files
- dev - development app to test if it works / looks ok.
- myCustomLib.js - barrel
- myCustomLib.d.ts
```

Within `dev` folder try to run an app. I bootstrap my module:

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule }                from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { NgModule }                     from "@angular/core";
import { AppComponent }                 from "./app.component";
import { MyCustomModule }               from "../../myCustomLib";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        MyCustomModule
    ],
    declarations: [ AppComponent ],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Now using the webpack I bundle my dev app.

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./app/boot",
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: "./bundle.js",
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts'],
        modules: [
            'node_modules'
        ]
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }, {
            test: /\.ts$/,
            loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }]
    },
    watch: true
};
```

But when I try to load the app I get a message:

```
metadata_resolver.js:230
Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'MyCustomModule' imported by the module 'AppModule'
```

My barrel file I import looks like:

**myCustomLib.js**

```
export * from './lib/myCustomLib.module';
```

I found also [hint on similar topic on github](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1831#issuecomment-242401992), but changing it to:

```
export { MyCustomModule } from './lib/myCustomLib.module';
```

did not help. I have also tried to import the module from `src` directory - same error. MyCustomModule should be ok as It was working fine with systemJS before.

**myCustomLib.module.ts:**

```
import { NgModule }                     from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }                from '@angular/platform-browser';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule
    ]
})
export class MyCustomModule {}
```

Any idea what can be the reason of this error? I have seen similar topics here but no answer or hint helped.

**Edit**: To make the example even simpler I have removed all from  MyCustomModule - same problem...

Comment: Can it be that one of your MyCustomComponent are declared in AppComponent ? I'm also getting this kind of message when one Component is referenced twice

Comment: Nope. I have just double checked that. the only thing I import is  MyCustomModule. All other have even unique names so it's not that.

Comment: Facing the same issue right now, did you find a solution ?

Comment: Problem in my opinion is related to the webpack v2. Moving to webpack 1.13.2 solves the issue. Take a look also at this discussion: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11438

Comment: @Baumi, did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @vlio20 - take a look at my comment just above yours.

Comment: I am getting these as well, yet in core/2.1.2.
It seems to be to be related to order of or multiple exports in company of @DeCorator - reFactoring out multiple exports has solved this error for me.

Comment: is your `myCustomLib.js` an external (npm?) module or it is a part of your application

Comment: In that case my `myCustomLib.js` was my application that I wanted to publish to npm.

Comment: As far as I remember, because `MyCustomModule` is a module on its own, you should use a non relative import, `import { MyCustomModule }               from "myCustomLib"`, and perhaps adjust your `resolve.modules`

Comment: I think it's the files extension problem, why is it .js ? shouldn't it be .ts ? because if it's not .ts , awesome-typescript-loader won't transpile it

Comment: why not importing the module directly ?

Comment: Could not reproduce problem with latest version of angular 2 webpack starter. Maybe worth a try to start from there?

Comment: Since you're not specifically excluding *.d.ts files in the webpack loader. It might pick this up?

Comment: you should make a demo repo to reproduce the issue, then helpers can find ways to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

in `myCustomLib.js`, try to import before exporting

```js
import { MyCustomModule } from './lib/myCustomLib.module;

export MyCustomModule;
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the lib folder to your [webpack configuration for resolving modules](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/).The path should be relative to the location of the webpack config file.

```
resolve: {
   modules: ['node_modules','lib']
```

Answer (score 0):

your MyCustomModule should be inside the src/app folder as it is not recognised by compiler because compiler, compiles all the files in the src folder ,thats why it is not recognising your module